# Spring Boot - Loading Initial Data to Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a little problem. I have a `Spring Boot` Application and I will fill my `H2` database with data. But I can not load the initial database data from the `data-h2.sql` file.

Model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "mood")
public class Mood {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "mood_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Mood(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Mood(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

`data-h2.sql` file:

```
INSERT INTO mood (name) VALUES ('Good');
```

`application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mooddb;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=a
spring.datasource.password=a
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `Spring Boot` expects to find a file with either the name `schema.sql` or `data.sql` in the classpath to load.

But your file is named `data-h2.sql` so spring will not consider it, even if it is correctly placed in `resources` location (i.e either `src/main/resources/` or `src/test/resources`).

It could search for a file with the name `data-h2.sql` and load it if you had configured the property `spring.datasource.platform = h2`.

Without using the aforementioned property, there are 2 solutions:

1. Rename the file into `data.sql` and be sure it is inside the resources folder
2. Do not rename the file and use the following application property to inform spring about the name of the file that it should load `spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:data-h2.sql`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works :)

Comment: @Susanne please accept the answer if it has helped you solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

The How-To guide is [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization).

And the property is named:

```
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
```

> Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your JDBC `DataSource` or R2DBC `ConnectionFactory` and initialize it (DML scripts). **It loads** SQL from the standard root classpath locations: `schema.sql` and `data.sql`, respectively. **In addition**, Spring Boot processes the `schema-${platform}.sql` and `data-${platform}.sql` files (if present), where platform is the value of `spring.sql.init.platform`. This allows you to switch to database-specific scripts **if necessary**. For example, you might choose to set it to the vendor name of the database (`hsqldb, h2, oracle, mysql, postgresql`, and so on). By default, SQL database initialization is only performed when using an embedded in-memory database. ...

---

```
 spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

... on the other hand:

> This will defer data source initialization until after any `EntityManagerFactory` beans have been created and initialized. `schema.sql` can then be used to make additions to any schema creation performed by Hibernate and `data.sql` can be used to populate it.

(**Manually** with `EnitityManager`, as I understand)

---

Please also consider:

> It is recommended to use a single mechanism for schema generation.

(So, not hibernate + scripts (+ migration tool)!)

---

And:

> Spring Boot supports two higher-level migration tools: Flyway and Liquibase.

---

A common pattern (for DDL) is:

1. To generate/log DDL scripts with hibernate/jpa (e.g. when new entities evolve)
2. To use these in flyway/liquibase.